# How do they get from $Ac=0$ to $Q^tQRc=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

How do they get from $Ac=0$ to $Q^tQRc=0$ in this proof at this link in the problem 1 when they solve for b?

http://www.math.pitt.edu/~swigon/Matlab/Homework2_sols.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, its transpose $Q^t$ is its inverse, i.e., $\color{green}{Q^tQ=I}$, the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Multiplying on the left by $Q^t$ gives
$$
Q^t(QR)c = (\color{green}{Q^tQ})\,Rc = \color{green}{I}\,Rc = Rc.
$$
If we combine this with the fact that $\color{red}{Ac = 0}$, then we see
$$
Rc = Q^t(QR)c = Q^t\color{red}{Ac} = Q^t\color{red}{0} = 0,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you. I see that now. I guess I am confused since Ac=0 how does that imply that $Q^tQRc=0$ because $A=QR$?. In other words how does QR = $Q^TQR$?

Comment: @Math4Life We're not saying that $QR = Q^tQR$. We're using the fact that $Q^tQ = I$ to show that $Rc = 0$. We do that by multiplying the equation $Ac = 0$ on the left by $Q^t$.